# how can use Action<Action<object>, object> ? Is this the right way?

Tags: c#, action

It is cumbersome to create a method for each object.
Can't it be used for each method of the same type by using only one action?

```
    Action<Action<object>, object> action;

    private void init_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // how write code?
        action = (a, o) =>
        {
            //Action<object>
            a(o);
        };
    }

    // this method used by another thread
    private void test(object obj)
    {   
        // i want this like. and use other methods.
        this.Invoke(action, listbox.Items.Add, obj);
    }
```

this befor code

```
    private void init_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listboxAdd = (obj) =>
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(obj);
        };
    }

    // this method used by another thread
    private void test(object obj)
    {
        this.Invoke(listboxAdd, obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listbox.Items.Add` has the same signature as `Action<object>`, so the compiler can use it directly when an `Action<object>` is needed. This should work:

```
private void test(object obj)
{
    this.Invoke(listbox.Items.Add, obj);
}
```

Comment: I've tried other ways to solve it, but the error still pops up.
CS1503 error...
i dont know...
this my code
https://github.com/customordermaid3d2/COM3D2.TCPLilly.Plugin/blob/fedc994b7a60e5068b80a2384e5f7f64f81cd144/COM3d2.TCPLilly.Client/TCPLillyClientUtill.cs#L127

Comment: ok!
this like solve.
actionObject(listMaid.Items.Add, maid.Value);
        internal void actionObject<T>(Func<Object,T> action, Object obj)
        {
            this.Invoke(action, obj);
        }